# Can I hide the Progress Indicator for different perspectives in Eclipse 3.x

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I refer specifically to the bar at he bottom of the screen that is controlled by this line:

```
configurer.setShowProgressIndicator(true);
```

I have my own way to switch perspectives so I could switch it on and off with some code as the perspectives are switched, but is there a way to switch it on and off during execution at all?

Thanks,

Glen x

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to change the progress indicator display once it has been shown.

You may be able to use the e4 model service API to turn off the rendering of the progress indicator:

```
EModelService modelService = .... get the model service


MToolControl pbElement = (MToolControl)modelService.find(
            "org.eclipse.ui.ProgressBar", model); 

pbElement.setToBeRendered(false);
```

Comment: Presumably can't do this in 3.x though?

Comment: Depends what you mean by 3.x. If you mean an actual Eclipse 3.x code base then no, but this should work for anything using Eclipse 4 even in 3.x compatibility mode.